# Referring to the previous string in an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm having trouble with arrays. Here's the code I have right now.

```
String english = "hip-hop";
    String[] words = english.split ("[\\s+]|(?<=-)|(?=-)");
    String[] latin = new String [words.length];
    String phrase = "";

    for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++)
    {
        int k;
        k = words.length - 1;

         latin [i] = words [i]; //stays the same
        if ((words [i].charAt (0) == '-') || (words [k].equals("-") == true)) //PROBLEM RIGHT HERE
        {
            phrase = phrase + latin [i]; //add latin to previous phrase
        }
        else
        {
            phrase = phrase + " " + latin [i]; //add latin to previous phrase
        }
    }
    System.out.println (phrase);
```

So the output for this program is : hip- hop
The correct output should be: hip-hop
I know it may seem pointless to break hip-hop and then recombine it, but it's a small thing i need to get right for the pig latin translator I am creating. 
The code here compiles correctly.

I created the int k so that if the previous word in the array is equal to "-", then when latin is added to the phrase, no space will be present.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you never update the value of `k` so `words[k].equals("-")` will never evaluate to true. It will always equal `hop`

Comment: i see what you mean. but when I do this, it does not work:
    int k;    
    k = i - 1;            
    k =k + 1; -->this is placed after the if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were never updating the value of `k` so the detection of the previous word being equal to `-` would never evaluate to `true`. Instead just use a variable to track the previous word like this.

```
String english = "hip-hop";
String[] words = english.split("[\\s+]|(?<=-)|(?=-)");
String[] latin = new String[words.length];
String phrase = "";

String previousWord = "";
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
   latin[i] = words[i];
   if (words[i].equals("-") || previousWord.equals("-")) {
      phrase = phrase + latin[i];
   } else {
      phrase = phrase + " " + latin[i];
   }
   previousWord = words[i];
}

System.out.println(phrase);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel that this addresses your question then accepting my answer is appreciated.